# Окно в Qt получается меньше чем в дизайнере

Tags: c++, windows, qt, windows-10

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

масштаб экрана 150%, но если его изменить, то ничего не меняется

Comment: Попробуйте поставить sizePolicy в Fixed для горизонтали и верикали.

Comment: @Unick Не помогло

Comment: Минимальные ширину и высоту поменяйте на те которые хотите

Comment: @vegorov Тоже ничего не поменялось

Comment: @ИванЛалетин Значит не поменяли минимальные ширину и высоту. Банально в конструкторe сделайте `setMinimumSize(QSize(600,600))`

Comment: @vegorov Спасибо. Но мне все же не понятно почему я в дизайнере не могу определить размер окна, виджетов и почему во время запуска проги они появляются в уменьшенном размере.

Comment: @ИванЛалетин Можете. Я создал пустой проект в QtCreator, выставил минимальные размеры окна в дизайнере, и всё. По-умолчанию там минимальные размеры - 0х0, максимальные - 2милларда на 2 миллиарды, и какая-то геометрия начальная, а при запуске в зависимости от sizePolicy подбираются размеры в пределах от min до max. В зависимости - в смысле в зависимости от контента окна, если оно пустое - то окно уменьшается. Я не эксперт, но вроде бы так работает.

Comment: @vegorov Поменял масштаб экрана на 100%, перезапустил ноут, запустил свое окошко и оно такого же размера как и в дизайнере(ура). Но кодить, к сожалению, с таким масштабом не оч - буквы слишком маленькие. Не знаю проблема в Qt или в чем то еще

Comment: @ИванЛалетин В QtCreator можно менять размер шрифта насколько я помню, только не помню где это в меню или горячие клавиши какие

Comment: @ИванЛалетин МенюQtCreator `Правка -> Дополнительно -> Увеличить/Уменьшить/Восстановить шрифт`

Answer (score 0):

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
   QMainWindow(parent),
   ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setMinimumSize(QSize(700, 700));
}
```